# Remove rows which have na values

Tags: python, py-datatable

I have the following `datatable` in python:-

```
#          A        B               B_lag_1         B_lag_2         B_lag_3         B_lag_4
#0         0        −0.342855       NA              NA              NA              NA
#1         0        0.0706784       −0.342855       NA              NA              NA
#2         0        0.0470259       0.0706784       −0.342855       NA              NA
#3         0        −0.0522357      0.0470259       0.0706784       −0.342855       NA
#4         0        −0.610938       −0.0522357      0.0470259       0.0706784       −0.342855
#5         1        −2.62617        NA              NA              NA              NA
#6         1        0.550128        −2.62617        NA              NA              NA
#7         1        0.538717        0.550128        −2.62617        NA              NA
#8         1        −0.487166       0.538717        0.550128        −2.62617        NA
#9         1        0.996788        −0.487166       0.538717        0.550128        −2.62617
```

From this, I want to remove all the rows which have any `na` values in them. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe you shouldn't create these `NA` in previous question [Create many lagged variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72463031/create-many-lagged-variables/72465998#72465998)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never used `datatable` but `pandas.DataFrame` has `isna()` to select rows with `na`, and `drop()` to remove rows (or it can use `del` for this) and I found similar functions for `datatable`.

- Official documentation: [Delete Rows/Columns](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/start/using-datatable.html#delete-rows-columns)
- Other place (found with Google): [Filtering out Empty Rows](https://samukweku.github.io/data-wrangling/python_datatable_row_selection.html#filtering-out-empty-rows)

---

`datatable` can use `del` to remove selected rows. It can use also `.isna()` or `== None` to select rows with `na`. Problem is that it can filter it only on one column - so it may need `for`-loop to check different columns.

```
columns = dt.f[:]

for n in range(1, 5):
    rows = (dt.f[f'B_lag_{n}'] == None)
    del df[rows, columns]

print(df)
```

This removes values from datatable but not rows and it create empty rows like this

```
   |     A          B    B_lag_1    B_lag_2    B_lag_3    B_lag_4
   | int64    float64    float64    float64    float64    float64
-- + -----  ---------  ---------  ---------  ---------  ---------
 0 |    NA  NA         NA         NA         NA         NA       
 1 |    NA  NA         NA         NA         NA         NA       
 2 |    NA  NA         NA         NA         NA         NA       
 3 |    NA  NA         NA         NA         NA         NA       
 4 |     0  -0.234153   1.52303    0.647689  -0.138264   0.496714
 5 |    NA  NA         NA         NA         NA         NA       
 6 |    NA  NA         NA         NA         NA         NA       
 7 |    NA  NA         NA         NA         NA         NA       
 8 |    NA  NA         NA         NA         NA         NA       
 9 |     1   0.54256   -0.469474   0.767435   1.57921   -0.234137
[10 rows x 6 columns]
```

It can be better to keep rows which don't have `None`

```
columns = dt.f[:]

for n in range(1, 5):
    rows = (dt.f[f'B_lag_{n}'] != None)
    df = df[rows, columns]

print(df)
```

Result:

```
   |     A          B    B_lag_1   B_lag_2    B_lag_3    B_lag_4
   | int64    float64    float64   float64    float64    float64
-- + -----  ---------  ---------  --------  ---------  ---------
 0 |     0  -0.234153   1.52303   0.647689  -0.138264   0.496714
 1 |     1   0.54256   -0.469474  0.767435   1.57921   -0.234137
[2 rows x 6 columns]
```

---

But you can use `&` (as operator `AND`) and `|` (as operator `OR`) to do the same without `for`-loop.

```
columns = dt.f[:]

rows = (dt.f['B_lag_1'] != None) & (dt.f['B_lag_2'] != None) & (dt.f['B_lag_3'] != None) & (dt.f['B_lag_4'] != None)

df = df[rows, columns]

print(df)
```

---

But later I found that `datatable` has `dt.rowall()` and `dt.rowany()` to work with many columns and code can be simpler.

- Other place (found with Google): [Filtering across Multiple Columns](https://samukweku.github.io/data-wrangling/python_datatable_row_selection.html#filtering-across-multiple-columns)

`rowall()` works like operator `AND`, `rowany()` works like operator `OR`.

```
columns = dt.f[:]

rows = dt.rowall(dt.f['B_lag_1', 'B_lag_2', 'B_lag_3', 'B_lag_4'] != None)
#rows = dt.rowall(dt.f['B_lag_1':'B_lag_4'] != None)  # range of columns
#rows = dt.rowall(dt.f[:] != None)                    # all columns

df = df[rows, columns]

print(df)
```

---

Full working code:

I took code from my previous answer [Create many lagged variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72465998/1832058)

```
import datatable as dt
import numpy as np

def test1(df):
    print('\n--- test 1 ---\n')
    
    df = df.copy()

    #columns = dt.f['A', 'B', 'B_lag_1', 'B_lag_2', 'B_lag_3', 'B_lag_4']
    #columns = df.keys()
    columns = dt.f[:]
    
    for n in range(1, 5):
        rows = (dt.f[f'B_lag_{n}'] == None)
        del df[rows, columns]

    print(df)    
        
def test2(df):
    print('\n--- test 2 ---\n')
    
    df = df.copy()

    #columns = dt.f['A', 'B', 'B_lag_1', 'B_lag_2', 'B_lag_3', 'B_lag_4']
    #columns = df.keys()
    columns = dt.f[:]

    for n in range(1, 5):
        rows = (dt.f[f'B_lag_{n}'] != None)
        df = df[rows, columns]
    
    print(df)

def test3(df):
    print('\n--- test 3 ---\n')
    
    df = df.copy()
    
    rows = (dt.f['B_lag_1'] != None) & (dt.f['B_lag_2'] != None) & (dt.f['B_lag_3'] != None) & (dt.f['B_lag_4'] != None)

    columns = dt.f[:]
    
    df = df[rows, columns]
    
    print(df)

def test4(df):
    print('\n--- test 4 ---\n')
    
    df = df.copy()

    columns = dt.f[:]
    
    #rows = dt.rowall(dt.f['B_lag_1', 'B_lag_2', 'B_lag_3', 'B_lag_4'] != None) # use columns in some range
    #rows = dt.rowall(dt.f['B_lag_1':'B_lag_4'] != None) # use columns in some range
    #rows = dt.rowall(dt.f[float] != None)               # use columns which have float values
    rows = dt.rowall(dt.f[:] != None)                    # use all columns

    df = df[rows, columns]
    
    print(df)
    
    
# --- main ---

np.random.seed(42)

df = dt.Frame({
    "A": np.repeat(np.arange(0, 2), 5), 
    "B": np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)
})

for n in range(1, 5):
    df[f'B_lag_{n}'] = df[:, dt.shift(dt.f.B, n), dt.by('A')]['B']

# --- tests ---

test1(df)
test2(df)
test3(df)
test4(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach, assuming your frame is `df` (updated 2022/Aug/12, thanks to comment by @Oleksiy K)

```
df[dt.rowcount(f[:])==df.ncols,:]
```

Output:

```
   |     A  B          B_lag_1     B_lag_2    B_lag_3    B_lag_4  
   | int64  str32      str32       str32      str32      str32    
-- + -----  ---------  ----------  ---------  ---------  ---------
 0 |     0  −0.610938  −0.0522357  0.0470259  0.0706784  −0.342855
 1 |     1  0.996788   −0.487166   0.538717   0.550128   −2.62617 
[2 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: To make it more generic one could do `df[dt.rowcount(f[:])==df.ncols, :]`